# How much functionality needed to create a new class?

Tags: c#, coding-standards, wpf

Right now I am working on my own small project of a WPF file back up application. I have come to a point where I want to create a method that will copy files recursively from one place to another.

This is not the first time that I ask myself the question:

> Should this method be a part of an existing class, or should I store it in a new class?

What bothers me the most is that if I create a new class, it will most likely consist of solely this method, so it seems like a stretch to create a whole new type for just one action. On the other hand, I believe it is a good abstraction. Copying files doesn't have much to do with a WPF window.

The example that I show here brings out a more general question. **How to balance between functionality/abstraction/readability to create code where OOP principles don't obscure common sense?** I am relatively new to programming, but I'd like to start following good coding practices as soon as possible, e.g. not implementing design patterns like crazy, because I have just read about them.

Comment: Something is a method if it needs access to a class's implementation details; otherwise it should be a function. Things that can be imported should be grouped with the things they're likely to be used with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main principle and purpose of OOP is to *combine your data with the logic that manipulates it.*  Ergo, if your new method has functionality that has specifically to do with a class, then it belongs with that class.

If your  recursive copy requires you to store any state in memory, like a byte queue or something like that, then make a RecursiveCopy class, and put your Copy method there.  If your recursive copy method is *stateless,* then make it a static method, and put it in a static utility class.